# Paper under review a second time without being sent back to author

Tags: peer-review

I submitted a paper to a journal and had it returned with "revise and resubmit".  After the revision was submitted, the journal's status page told me that it was under review.  Once the reviews were completed the status changed to "awaiting editor recommendation".  However, I checked it today and it appears to be back out for review.  Is this common?  Any ideas what it might mean?

Comment: Can you be more specific about which submission platform the journal you submitted to is using??

Answer (score 6):

This might indicate that the editor has decided that another review is necessary. For example, reviewers might have very different recommendations. It can also mean that some of the reviewers did not finish their review in time.
This happens sometimes and is not a cause for concern.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this sequence of statuses in the Elsevier system. 
I do not think it means anything bad for you. Maybe just a system mistake. Write another paper in the meantime...